# How to store binary data in pewee BlobField

Tags: python, sqlite, io, peewee

How can I store binary data `io.BytesIO()` in SQLlite DB using `peewee`?

When I try to store it in BlobField I'm getting following error:

```
ValueError: Value must be either a bytes, memoryview or BigBitFieldData instance.
```

Comment: It appears that you're not using `BlobField` but are using `BigBitField` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you're not actually using a `BlobField`. However, to store data from a BytesIO object into an *actual* `BlobField`, you can:

```
# io.BytesIO.getvalue() method should return bytes.
some_model.blob_field = bytesio_obj.getvalue()
```

Answer (score -2):

Building on the author's answer, I am putting a more end-to-end example here for people who aren't familiar with this the `io`

```
with open("file.parquet.gzip", "rb") as f:
    bytesio_obj = io.BytesIO(f.read())
    binary = bytesio_obj.getvalue()

some_model.blob_field = binary
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59365168/5739514