# Convert file into BytesIO object using python

Tags: python, bytesio

I have a file and want to convert it into `BytesIO` object so that it can be stored in database's varbinary column.

Please can anyone help me convert it using python.

Below is my code:

```
f = open(filepath, "rb")
print(f.read())

myBytesIO = io.BytesIO(f)
myBytesIO.seek(0)
print(type(myBytesIO))
```

Comment: `BytesIO` simulates a file stream from a buffer.  if you just want the byte data, `data = f.read()` is all you need.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, if what you are working with accepts a `BytesIO` object then you should just be able to pass `f`, but note, don't `read` from it first.

Comment: Use a context manager to handle the file!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Opening a file with `open` and mode read-binary already gives you a Binary I/O object.

> [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o):
>
> The easiest way to create a binary stream is with open() with 'b' in the mode string:
>
> `f = open("myfile.jpg", "rb")`

So in normal circumstances, you'd be fine just passing the file handle wherever you need to supply it. If you *really* want/need to get a `BytesIO` instance, just pass the bytes you've read from the file when creating your `BytesIO` instance like so:

```py
from io import BytesIO

with open(filepath, "rb") as fh:
    buf = BytesIO(fh.read())
```

This has the disadvantage of loading the entire file into memory, which might be avoidable if the code you're passing the instance to is smart enough to stream the file without keeping it in memory. Note that the example uses `open` as a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers) that will reliably close the file, even in case of errors.

Comment: I, for one, certainly hope the code I am passing the bytesIO to is _not_ "smart" enough to stream the file from disk, as I am trying to keep the harddrive busy loading and saving, rather than waiting for loaded files to be processed.